# How to fill every 2nd row with start time and end time of non-events

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data with start times and end times of certain events (subjects gazing at an object called `Center`).

```
test <- data.frame(
  gaze_at = c("Center", "Center", "Center"),
  start = c(1.4, 2.5, 4.4),
  end = c(1.66, 2.8, 4.93)
)
```

I would like to 'fill up' the dataframe with the start times and end times of the participant *not* gazing at `Center` by inserting these times into every second row of the dataframe. The desired output is this:

```
test1 <- data.frame(
  gaze_at = c("Center", "NonCenter", "Center", "NonCenter", "Center", "NonCenter"),
  start = c(1.4, 1.66, 2.5, 2.8, 4.4, 4.93),
  end = c(1.66, 2.5, 2.8, 4.4, 4.93, NA)
)
```

I've tried using `tidyverse::unnest` but that didn't work. How can this transformation be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
test %>% uncount(2) %>% mutate(gaze_at = case_when(!row_number()%%2 ~ 'NonCenter', TRUE ~ gaze_at), 
                               start = case_when(!row_number()%%2 ~ lag(end), TRUE ~ start), 
                               end = case_when(!row_number()%%2 ~ lead(start), TRUE ~ end))
    gaze_at start  end
1    Center  1.40 1.66
2 NonCenter  1.66 2.50
3    Center  2.50 2.80
4 NonCenter  2.80 4.40
5    Center  4.40 4.93
6 NonCenter  4.93   NA
```

Comment: Cool solution. I'm not familiar with `%%`. What does it do?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, it's modulus operator, it gives the remainder of an equation. Here, we are looking for even numbered rows. For example for the second row, 2%%2 remainder is 0, but with negation (!), we are making it 1 which is TRUE.

Comment: fantastic solution @KarthikS

Answer (score 2):

Another tidyr solution

```
library(tidyverse)

test_1 <- test %>% mutate(id = row_number())

test_2 <- test_1 %>% mutate(gaze_at2 = "non-centre",
                start2 = end,
                end2 = lead(start)) %>%
  select(id:end2) %>% rename(gaze_at = gaze_at2,
                             start = start2,
                             end = end2)
test1 <- rbind(test_1, test_2) %>% arrange(id) %>% select(-id)

> test1
    gaze_at start  end
1    Center  1.40 1.66
2 NonCenter  1.66 2.50
3    Center  2.50 2.80
4 NonCenter  2.80 4.40
5    Center  4.40 4.93
6 NonCenter  4.93   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the missing lines using the original table with `data.frame` and then `rbind` them and resorting the result to alternating lines using `matrix`.

```
i <- seq_len(nrow(test))
x <- data.frame("NonCenter", test[,3], test[i+1,2])
names(x) <- names(test)
rbind(test, x)[c(matrix(c(i,i+length(i)), 2, byrow = TRUE)),]
#rbind(test, x)[c(matrix(seq_len(length(i)*2), 2, byrow = TRUE)),] #Alternative
#    gaze_at start  end
#1    Center  1.40 1.66
#4 NonCenter  1.66 2.50
#2    Center  2.50 2.80
#5 NonCenter  2.80 4.40
#3    Center  4.40 4.93
#6 NonCenter  4.93   NA
```

or first repeat each row and update the content afterwards.

```
i <- seq_len(nrow(test))
x <- test[rep(i, each=2),]
j <- seq(2, nrow(x), 2)
#j <- c(FALSE, TRUE) #Alternative
x[j,1] <- "NonCenter"
x[j,2] <- test[,3]
x[j,3] <- test[i+1,2]
x
#      gaze_at start  end
#1      Center  1.40 1.66
#1.1 NonCenter  1.66 2.50
#2      Center  2.50 2.80
#2.1 NonCenter  2.80 4.40
#3      Center  4.40 4.93
#3.1 NonCenter  4.93   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I have only used for loop.
Does that help?

```
New_gaze <- vector()
New_start <- vector()
New_end <- vector()
for (l in 1:nrow(test)) {
  k = l
  New_gaze <- append(New_gaze,"center")
  New_start <- append(New_start,test$start[k])
  New_end <- append(New_end,test$end[k])
  k = l+1
  New_gaze <- append(New_gaze,"Non center")
  New_start <- append(New_start,test$end[k-1])
  New_end <- append(New_end,test$start[k])

}
df <- data.frame(New_gaze,New_start,New_end)

> df
    New_gaze New_start New_end
1     center      1.40    1.66
2 Non center      1.66    2.50
3     center      2.50    2.80
4 Non center      2.80    4.40
5     center      4.40    4.93
6 Non center      4.93      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also have  a two step solution: Create a new df with the missing "Non-Center"-times using `lead`.

````
# create second df
df_helper <- data.frame(
  gaze_at = rep("Non-Center", nrow(test)),
  start = test$end,
  end = lead(test$start)
)

# combine & order
df <- rbind(test, df_helper)
df[order(df$start), ]```
````

Comment: `length(test)` counts the number of columns; should be `nrow(test)`. But I still like the solution; please amend.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively could use `lead` to select the start from next row, `add_row` to add the result of `mutate` as a new row, `select` to select the columns, and then `arrange` to sort by start and end columns.

```
test %>% 
mutate(start_n = end, end_n = lead(start), gaze_at_n = "NonCenter") %>% 
add_row(start = .$start_n, end= .$end_n, gaze_at = .$gaze_at_n) %>% 
select(gaze_at, start,end) %>% 
arrange(start,end)
```

Should give:

```
  gaze_at start  end
1    Center  1.40 1.66
2 NonCenter  1.66 2.50
3    Center  2.50 2.80
4 NonCenter  2.80 4.40
5    Center  4.40 4.93
6 NonCenter  4.93   NA
```